# Sony A7Sii not showing expected API features

Tags: camera, sony

I'm trying to control a Sony a7SII via the pysony Sony Camera API wrapper.

https://github.com/Bloodevil/sony_camera_api

I'm able to connect to the camera, start the session, but I'm not getting the expected list of possible API functions back.

My process looks like this:

```
import pysony
api = pysony.SonyAPI()
api.startRecMode()

api.getAvailableApiList()
{'id': 1, 'result': [['getVersions', 'getMethodTypes', 'getApplicationInfo', 'getAvailableApiList', 'getEvent', 'actTakePicture', 'stopRecMode', 'startLiveview', 'stopLiveview', 'awaitTakePicture', 'getSupportedSelfTimer', 'setExposureCompensation', 'getExposureCompensation', 'getAvailableExposureCompensation', 'getSupportedExposureCompensation', 'setShootMode', 'getShootMode', 'getAvailableShootMode', 'getSupportedShootMode', 'getSupportedFlashMode']]}
```

As you can see, the returned list does not contain a full set of controls.
Specifically, I want to be able to set the shutter speed and aperture. Which based on this matrix https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/ I should be able to do.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, both pysony and the API are working fine.

You must install the Remote App from the store rather than relying on the "embedded" remote that ships with the camera to get full API functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Also as a note; it seems to take a little time for the 'api.startRecMode()' to actually update the available API list. Sensible to add a little delay to your code.

See:
src/example/dump_camera_capabilities.py